Geometry Nodes - Collection Info: turn off visibility of input collection
Here is a simple collection info example:

Blue cube is the original cube in the collection named Test, red is the one modified trough the collection info node acting on the Test collection.
Is there a way to turn off the visibility of the original (blue) cube both in the viewport as well as in the rendered image from within the geometry node?

You can make a driver

Brilliant idea! In deed you can put a driver on an objects "Hide Viewport" attribute. Unfortunately this doesn't work on collections. Now I have to find a way how to script bpy.data.collections["Test"].hide_viewport = True/False into another driver...

Geometry nodes can only change the objects they're modifying.
If your geometry nodes are on the red "plane", it can only change the "plane".
You can always click the buttons to make the original object invisible (it will still work int the "collection info" node).


Thanks, I know that but that means I can't automate a task based on Collection Info as the user needs to manually turn off the visibility of the collection. It's a half baked solution. :-(  The Collection Info node refers to a collection and modifies it's content and it could also "see" the collection's properties. (These properties are available in BPY so the programmer of the node could also have added this functionality. It would have been a logical step.

No, it's not logical. The collection info does not modify its content.  Nothing in geometry nodes is intended to modify anything that is not the object containing the modifier with the nodes.

"Geometry nodes can only change the objects they're modifying." - more specifically, it modifies the data of the object. It's the mesh or curve data, or pointcloud... Geometry Nodes won't modify constraints, transformation matrix, Line Art settings etc.

I think it is logical. The Collection Info is referring to objects which have otherwise no relation to the object which actually has the GN modifier. From a user's point of view  it is entirely logical that I want to do something with the objects in that referred collection and that might mean that I don't want to see the initial state of those objects. A simple "Hide Source" checkmark in the Collection Info node would be sufficient to achieve that. That's what I meant with half baked.
